# Build vim 7.4 with GUI support

Tags: unix, vim

I am trying to build vim 7.4 with GUI support but with no success in a SLES dev server in my local folder. Any help or hint is welcomed.

The configure script is executed with the following arguments:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/my_folder/bin/vim --enable-gui=gnome2 --with-gnome-lib=/usr/lib64
```

The config.log reports the following:

```
configure:7840: checking if X11 header files can be found
 configure:7856: gcc -c -g -O2    -I/usr/local/include conftest.c >&5
 conftest.c:17:27: fatal error: X11/Intrinsic.h: No such file or directory
 #include <X11/Intrinsic.h>
 ^
 compilation terminated.
 configure:7856: $? = 1
 configure: failed program was:
 | /* confdefs.h */
 | #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
 | #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
 | #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
 | #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
 | #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
 | #define PACKAGE_URL ""
 | #define UNIX 1
 | #define STDC_HEADERS 1
 | #define HAVE_SYS_WAIT_H 1
 | #define FEAT_NORMAL 1
 | #define USE_XSMP_INTERACT 1
 | #define HAVE_LIBNSL 1
 | #define FEAT_NETBEANS_INTG 1
 | /* end confdefs.h.  */
 | #include <X11/Xlib.h>
 | #include <X11/Intrinsic.h>
 | int
 | main ()
 | {
 |
 |   ;
 |   return 0;
 | }
 configure:7860: result: no
 configure:8098: checking --enable-gui argument                                                                                                                                                            
 configure:8158: result: no GUI support
 configure:9022: checking for X11/SM/SMlib.h
 configure:9022: result: no
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with SLES, but it sounds like you need the X11 development packages.  This seems to be the correct package:

https://www.suse.com/LinuxPackages/packageRouter.jsp?product=desktop&version=11&service_pack=&architecture=i386&package_name=xorg-x11-libx11-devel

If you search for xorg-x11-libX11-devel in Yast, does it come up?